# @implementation, vars and ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In my project There is a controller A with next code:

```
@implementation NKAddPostViewController
int _characterCounter = 512;
...
```

I change this variable in code, that it value is 400. Than i do `popViewControllerAnimated`.

But when i go to this controller again the value still 400. In `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` it still 400. **Why?** It seems that controller A is retained, but when i debug properties in `viewDidLoad`, they are `nill` until they are initialized again.

Here is the implementation of transfer, so nothing retain controllerA:

```
NKAddPostViewController *aContr = [NKAddPostViewController new];
[self.navigationController aContr animated:YES];
```

2 questions:

1. **So why _characterCounter retains?**
2. **Why when controller initializing the line `int _characterCounter = 512;`
   don't assign 512 to _characterCounter?**

Comment: why do you declare it inside implementation? it doesn't look like instance variable but rather like global one

Comment: @Abhinandan Re your edit: There is no reason to add the [xcode] tag here. Also the backticks are for `code` and not for general emphasis.

Comment: It's global value. I need it in two methods in my Class. So i have a choice: 1) Implement like ivar in `interface`. 2) implement like property. 3) implement like ivar in `implementation` and immediately assign value. 3-rd way is easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you say "3) implement like ivar in implementation and immediately assign value. 3-rd way is easier and faster"

3rd way is wrong. "ivar in implementation" is actually a private static variable, and does not do what you want.

You can create a private category and define a new instance variable there:

In your .m file, add this:

```
@interface NKAddPostViewController()
{
  int _characterCounter;
}

- (instancetype) init;
{
  self = [super init]; 
  if (!self) 
    return nil;
  _characterCounter  = 512;
}
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: I noticed, that  "ivar in implementation" have behaviour like static variable. But is it true, where did you know it from? I mean i don't write it like `static int _characterCounter = 512;`

Comment: What's a "private category"? Do you mean a *class extension*: `@interface NKAddPostViewController()`?

Comment: Yes, they are 2 different names for the same thing.

Comment: It isn't really a class extension because it isn't visible or usable outside of the implementation of the class. Also, since it's defined in the .m for the class, you can add instance variables there, where you normally can't do that in a "regular" class extension.

Comment: @DuncanC So if you want a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3): It's declared with parentheses.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, I guess you're right and class extension is the correct term for it. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @DuncanC The point why I was nagging isn't the term, but the fact that you forgot the `()` in you code.

Comment: Oh crap, I did? I did! That's not good. I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you did is declare a global variable.  It's not tied to the class at all, and has absolutely nothing to do with it.  Assigning the value of 512 happens when the app loads (really at build time), and only "happens" once.  Because it's global, any value you set remains until you change it again.

If you want an instance variable that's tied to the class, declare it like this...

```
@implementation NKAddPostViewController
{
    int _characterCounter;
}
```

Note that you can't initialize variables with the declaration.  Use your `init` override or `viewDidLoad:`.