# Where to put const in the class of Objective C

Tags: objective-c

If I put a const to the objective C class,

```
@implementation CLASS_A
    const NSString* TAG=@"CLASS_A";
@end
```

I found const TAG become global variable. And I cannot put two @implementation, each which has a TAG, in one .m file

```
@implementation CLASS_A
    const NSString* TAG=@"CLASS_A";
@end

@implementation CLASS_B
    const NSString* TAG=@"CLASS_B";  (Error)
@end
```

I would like TAG to link to each class with different name. Where will I put the const NSString* TAG=@"CLASS_A" and  TAG=@"CLASS_B" in the class?

I also tried this, but got errors.

```
@implementation CLASS_A
{
    const NSString* TAG=@"CLASS_A";  (Error)
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you literally just using the class name as the tag or is this an example? If you are using the class name then you can just use `NSStringFromClass`

Comment: Paul.s, I also use more than one const, like int MAX_ARRAY=20, I do not want it become global.

Comment: If it's private to the class then you can declare it as a `static NSString *const  *TAG = ..." within the implementation of the class.

Comment: In one .m file, I can not put two TAG, TAG="CLASS_A", and TAG="CLASS_B".

Comment: Don't put two classes in one file...

Comment: If I put them in different files, but in a header file, it has [extern NSString* TAG], have problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912666/implementation-vars-and-arc

Answer (score 0):

Create a class method to get the tag externally:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (NSString *)tag;
...
@end
```

and define it using a `static` in the implementation file (`.m`):

```
#import "MyClass.h"

static NSString * const _tag = @"A tag";

@implementation MyClass

+ (NSString *)tag
{
    return  _tag;
}
```

Note: you should implement one class per implementation file.

Comment: Hi Droppy, if I use [static NSString * const _tag = @"A tag";],  _tag is a global variable?

Comment: @L.Feng It can only be seen from within the implementation file.  So if you have `_tag` variables defined in the same way in other implementation files you will *not* get a duplicate symbol linker error.

Comment: in a header file if I define [extern NSString* _tag], will cause problem?

Comment: No, however that will make `_tag` global and you can only ever have one of them in the entire app/framework.